# Xhprof gui падает при выводе графов

Tags: apache, php, linux

Доброго дня! Очень прошу помощи.

Поставил тут xhprof для php на ubuntu 14.04... Сам он работает как надо: делает отчеты, кладет их в выбранную папку, дает их просматривать в GUI, но вот беда: при попытке глянуть графический вариант (ссылка [View Full Callgraph]) ложится намертво и иной раз даже приходится перезапускать апач, т.к. сайты на машине перестают грузиться. Graphviz поставлен. Сам gui вынесен отдельным виртуальным хостом и настроен, как остальные проекты (если честно, то в настройке хостов не сильно разбираюсь и просто скопировал рабочий вариант, переписав пути). Вот настройка:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin username1@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xhprof-0.9.4/xhprof_html/
<Directory /var/www/xhprof-0.9.4/xhprof_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
</Directory>
    ServerName xhprof
    ServerAlias www.xhprof.com
    ErrorLog /logs/e.log
    CustomLog /logs/a.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

В логах хоста ошибок нет. Вывод ошибок в php.ini включен. Возможно ошибки заносятся в какой-то другой лог? В общем, прошу помощи у знающих людей. Как быть, где смотреть?

Comment: может быть такое, что callgraph.php выедает больше памяти, чем определено в php.ini ?

Если этой информации нет в /logs/e.log, попробуйте поискать ее в /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: @makbeth, подозреваю, что там гигантский файл, на котором почему-то валится апач. Попробуйте поставить nginx, они свободно могут бегать в паре с апачем на разных портах. Еще можно пробовать вручную открывать html из папки xhprof_html.

Comment: Очень странно, но он ни с того ни с сего начал строить графы. Т.е. я вообще ничего не трогал ни с конфигами, ни с xhprof... Даже машину не перезагружал... Может, действительно была проблема с памятью? Возможно на тот момент что-то забило память и xhprof вис из-за ее недостатка, а теперь память освободилась, и он начал нормально работать... В общем, мистика да и только.